# Applying functions to variable references rather than copies in R

Tags: r, reference

### Context

I have multiple `data.table`, each assigned to their own variable, `dt1`, `dt2` etc. I wanted to apply a function to `dt1`, `dt2`, ..., and **preserve the original variable names**. I wanted to avoid hard-coded syntax like `dt1 <- foo(dt1)`, `dt2 <- foo(dt2)`. My solution is below.

```
dataSets <- list(dt1 = dt1, dt2 = dt2, dt3 = dt3, dt4 = dt4, dt5 = dt5)
for (i in 1:length(dataSets)) {
  dataSet <- dataSets[[i]]
  name <- names(dataSets)[i]
  assign(name, foo(dataSet))
}
```

I don't think my solution is very elegant. I dislike how I'm using `name` and `assign`.

### Question

How, if possible, can I rework what I've done, to avoid needing `name` and `assign`?

### My Thoughts

I imagine the solution might involve working with references to `dt1`, `dt2`, ...., rather than copies. I thought of creating a `referenceList`. It wouldn't copy`dt1`, `dt2`, .... Instead, it would point to those variables. I imagined creating a `referenceList`, like `rl <- referenceList(dt1)`. Then, applying `foo` to `rl`, `foo(rl[1])` would change `dt1`.

Comment: Is `foo()` your own custom function, or are you calling something written by someone else?

Comment: It is my own custom function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

R doesn't have a way to create references to variables in general. (Some kinds of objects, e.g. environments, are always dealt with via references, but most aren't.)

The usual way to do something like what you're doing is to put the objects in a list, and just work on the list, without bothering to extract them again.  For example,

```
dataSets <- list(dt1 = dt1, dt2 = dt2, dt3 = dt3, dt4 = dt4, dt5 = dt5)
for (i in seq_along(dataSets) {
  dataSets[[i]] <- foo(dataSets[[i]])
}
```

If you really want the results back in the original objects, I wouldn't bother putting all of those objects into a list, I'd work on a vector of names.  For example:

```
names <- paste0("dt", 1:5)
for (i in seq_along(names)) {
  assign(names[i], foo(get(names[i])))
}
```

But this is much less elegant than just working with the data in a list.

Comment: Thanks @user2554330. At the heart of my question was does R support a way to create references to variables in general? And, you've answered this, thank you! The question was very hypothetical, so, I typically follow your first point and work with lists. Your suggestion to work with `names` is a good one if I wanted to work with the variables outside the list.